# How does the Prothean assault rifle trigger ammo powers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After getting Prothean squad member, I unlocked Prothean assault rifle. I wondering, since it has unique mehanics, how ammo power (in my case, incinerate ammo) is triggered while using this weapon?

Comment: are you asking how yo activate it in gameplay, or how it works according to the game's science?

Comment: @Haydeen - I'm talking about how does it work with ammo powers. Normal rifle has chance per bullet to trigger effects - question is how partical beam works with triggering effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a weapon does damage, it has a chance to trigger the ammo power. Chance varies based on weapon type (otherwise a shotgun shot spread of 3, 6, or 8 pellets would more often than not trigger the power)

The Prothean Rifle triggering ammo powers is no different than the Scorpion (exploding pistol), Arc Pistol (energy pistol), or Geth Plasma Shotgun (energy ball shotgun) triggering them - inexplicable, but useful.